# setInterval in Javascript Running To Fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this sort of information floating around but I cannot figure out why my particular setup is flashing through the function so fast.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have squares on a page that I need to glow in order, but 500 milliseconds apart. I store the jQuery identifier in an array and cycle through it.

```
function glow(source) {// glows
  $(source).addClass("square-active")
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $(source).removeClass("square-active");
  }, 500);
}

function iterator() {
  var y = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
     for (var t=0; t<newComp.slice(0, numTurn).length; t++) {
          glow(squareArr[newComp[t]].div) 
       y = y + 1
} 
    }, 500 * y)
      }
```

I know that the squares are being iterated through properly because I have that logged to the console for verification purposes. I can see the squares flash in order, but it is insanely fast.

When I attempt to wrap the glow() function in setInterval I do not believe it works either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to schedule (using `setTimeout`) a set of functions which capture the index of each square, 500 msec apart to highlight the square.

```
function iterator() {
    for (let t=0; t<newComp.slice(0, numTurn).length; t++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
             glow(squareArr[newComp[t]].div) 
        }, 500 * t)
    }
}
```

uses the `let` keyword to capture the value of `t` in the lexical scope record of the nested function which calls `glow`. If you want to reinstate the `y` variable go ahead - it just seems to have the same value as `t`.

Usage of `let` is important. See the frequently asked question [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5217142) for ways of capturing the value of loop variables within a closure without using `let`.

Comment: Changing to "let" from "var" in the for loop did rectify this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your setTimeout to inside of the for loop

```
function iterator() {
  var y = 0;
  for (var t=0; t<newComp.slice(0, numTurn).length; t++) {
setTimeout(function() {
        glow(squareArr[newComp[t]].div) 
       y = y + 1
},500);
      }
```

Comment: I have changed to this, and now it only flashes the last item in the array. This leads me to believe the problem may be elsewhere then.

Answer (score 0):

That is because everytime the ***glow***() function is called, a new instance of the **anonymous** function() is created which is completely different from the previous instance, it so happens that just when the timeout of **instance** **x** of the anonymous function finishes, **instance y** also completes, which means you have ***newComp.slice(0, numTurn).length*** anonymous functions each with their own timeout of 500ms creating a very fast glow.